# How to use 2 condition in mysql query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Can anyone tell me what is the wrong with this query ? This code is not working:

```
SELECT index_no FROM test_record_tbl WHERE year='2012' and year='2013';
```

This code is working:

```
SELECT index_no FROM test_record_tbl WHERE year='2012' or year='2013';
```

Comment: Read about difference between 'and' & 'or', buddy

Comment: What do you mean by not working are you getting any error or there is no result in case 1?

Comment: If there is no result then it depends upon your 'and' or 'or' condition.

Comment: In general, please don't just say something is "not working". Say specifically what your error is, and what you tried to do to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get `index_no` which record belongs on year `2012` and `2013`.

This problem is often called `Relational Division`.

```
SELECT  index_no 
FROM    test_record_tbl 
WHERE   year IN ('2012', '2013')
GROUP   BY index_no
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 2
```

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Answer (score 3):

You're failing because the year can (presumably) never be both 2012 AND 2013.

And is an exclusive operator, meaning that both conditions MUST BE TRUE for the statement to evaluate as true.

OR means one, OR the other, OR both

Comment: I want to get data from year 2012 and 2013 

how to change it for get values from both years

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `and` and `or`.

You can **never** have year 2012 and year 2013 at the same time, but a year can fall either in year 2012 or year 2013.

That's why your first SQL query brought no result, while the second did.